# Hibernate Envers conditional auditing, custom EnversIntegrator ignored at runtime

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I need to configure conditional auditing using Hibernate Envers and Spring.

The default configuration works, but I want only the delete operations to be audited, saving the deleted entity in the audit table.

I've followed [all the documentation steps](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d5e4477) but when I try the application with a simple main that creates and deletes an entity, my CustomEnversIntegrator is not called, instead the org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversIntegrator is called.

Here is my spring-config.xml:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.default_schema">macap_auditoria</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix">aud_</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix"></prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister">false</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.cascade_delete_revision">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    ......
```

CustomEnversIntegrator.java, listening only to the delete operation:

```
    public class CustomEnversIntegrator extends EnversIntegrator {

private AuditConfiguration enversConfiguration;

@Override
public void integrate(Configuration configuration, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    final EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
    listenerRegistry.addDuplicationStrategy(EnversListenerDuplicationStrategy.INSTANCE);
    enversConfiguration = AuditConfiguration.getFor(configuration, serviceRegistry.getService(ClassLoaderService.class));
    if (enversConfiguration.getEntCfg().hasAuditedEntities()) {
        listenerRegistry.prependListeners(EventType.POST_DELETE, new CustomEnversPostDeleteEventListener(enversConfiguration));
    }
}
```

}

And lastly, I've added the file META-INF/services/org.hibernate.spi.Integrator
with one line inside: uy.com.macap.ccd.services.persistence.audit.CustomEnversIntegrator

The jar generated in my .m2 folder contains the META-INF/services/org.hibernate.spi.Integrator file inside, so I don't know what else to try besides recompiling envers with the EnversIntegrator class modified by me.

Thanks.

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using? Are you using the same Envers and Hibernate versions? How are you deploying your app, does the jar that is deployed contain the META-INF file?

Comment: I've tried 4.3.7 and 4.3.8. Yes, I'm using the same version for both Envers and Hibernate. Currently I'm not deploying the app, just "testing" it with some code in a Main class. The jar generated by maven does contain the META-INF/services/org.hibernate.spi.Integrator file.

Comment: How you test with your main class? Do you load full Spring Context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the name the of the file under `META-INF/services`. According to the documentation, it should be

```
org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
```

and *not*

```
org.hibernate.spi.Integrator
```

as in your post.